# the browser is opening but the website is not loading even on using driver.get() in selenium

Tags: selenium

Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 87, so returning the closest version found: 86
Dec 14, 2020 4:51:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 87 of 86

rg.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: 'de8579b6d5'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-CNV1FUE', ip: '192.168.0.171', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.88, chrome:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the old selenium maven dependency 3.14 on updating it to 4.0.0 it worked fine the website loaded in the browser

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
</dependency>
```